# Saving a sheet as a cell name when selecting cells and saving as a PDF

Tags: vba, excel

This might be basic and I have tried a lot of the suggested answers but I can't get it right, maybe because I am specifying certain cells for saving (as there is a lot more I done want saved every time).

I am trying to get the sheet to save as cell C20 but if I add in after Filename Range ("C20") it won accept it....

Here is my code so far (as you can see im on test 9 now and going around in circles)

```
Sub Testsave9()
'
' Testsave9 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=33
    Range("A1:J46").Select
    Range("A46").Activate
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= 
        "L:\Liberty 2017\Luke\Despatch Test\Despatch Save Location\NameHere.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

In this code I have saved it simple as 'NameHere' in the save as box. How to I tell Excel to save it as the value in cell C20 whilst keeping the print specifications?

Thanks

Luke

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    "L:\Liberty 2017\Luke\Despatch Test\Despatch Save Location\" & Range("C20").Text & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

However, you will need to ensure that C20 contains only characters that can be used in a filename etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting an error on that...

Compile Error:

Syntex Error

With the first line being highlighted. The cell c20 is only containing number and letters.

Comment: It might be a copy/paste error. Try putting an underscore after `filename:=` (I'll change my answer)

Comment: Glad to help. If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark it as such.